# Examples for bidirectional and unidirectional relationships between objects

Tags: design, multithreading, education, object, relationships

To better demonstrate the difficulties of reading/updating objects in a multithreaded environment, I'm looking for examples for groups of objects with a bidirectional or unidirectional relationship between them such that if one is *updated* then the other(s) may update also.

*Notes:*

1. *updated* equals to - the former state of the object is no longer valid so a new object with different value(s) must be created (No setters; Functional style).
2. I'm not looking for any kind of synchronization solutions.

---

Examples I created/found so far:

> The notation `B -> A` means that `B` state may derive from `A` state and if `A` is *updated* then `B` may/may not update due to `A` update.

1. unidirectional relationship: A download contains the following characteristics:

   - `is download started: boolean` - Can be set to `true` only once.
   - `is currently downloading: boolean` - Will be `true` when `is download started` is `true`. will be `false when`is download completed`will be`false`. Also, it may change from`true` to false and vice-versa by the user.
   - `download speed: number` - Will change as soon as `is currently downloading` is `true`
   - `is download completed: boolean` - Can be `true` iff `is currently downloading` is `true`.

relationships:

`is download completed -> is currently downloading -> is download started` and `download speed -> is currently downloading`

2. bidirectional relationship: A `master` who's responsible for multiple `slaves` (jobs). A `master` and a `slave` contains the following characteristics:

`master`:

- `state: In progress/Canceled/Completed` - It starts with `In progress` state and will be `Completed` iff all `slaves` have `Completed` state.
- `slaves: slave[]`

`slave`:

- `state: In progress/Canceled/Completed` - It starts with `In progress` state. Will be `Canceled` iff the `master`'s state is `Canceled` and it states is `In progress`.

relationships:

`master: state -> slaves: state`, `master: slave[] -> slaves: state` and `slave: state -> master: state`.

---

**Bonus:** Example for a group of objects with a bidirectional relationship which can be changed to a unidirectional relationship after realizing there was a design problem - But isn't easy to see immediately.

Comment: You've already stipulated in your opening paragraphs that you will be using immutable objects, so why does any of this matter?

Comment: Good question - because if we request the state of each of them individually, meanwhile, there may be an update so I may get a group of results which, together, are invalid. There are solutions like Redux (which itself have some downsides) to solve this kind of problems. This question is about the problem and not the solution. Thanks

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)